# Docker in Docker: docker daemon doesn't start (Failed to connect to containerd)

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, dockerfile

I'm trying to install docker inside a docker container based on ubuntu:14.04.
When I start the daemon with `docker daemon` I get an error:

> FATA[0000] Failed to connect to containerd. Please make sure containerd is installed in your PATH or you have specificed the correct address. Got error: write /proc/43/oom_score_adj: permission denied

How can I fix this? Here the dockerfile I used to set up the image:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates

# Adds the new GPG key
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D

# add entry
RUN echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

# update and purge the old repo if it exists
RUN apt-get update && apt-get purge lxc-docker

# Verify that APT is pulling from the right repository
RUN apt-cache policy docker-engine

# Install the recommended packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y linux-image-extra-virtual

# install docker
RUN apt-get install -y docker-engine
```

Comment: do you run the base container in priviliged mode? you could also check DIND image on github!

Comment: Thank you! This is actually the answer. Quite embarrassing, I didn't run the container in privileged mode.